# How can I use PHP foreach in the following example?

Tags: php, html, function, checkbox, foreach

I have a big issue right now in using php foreach function.

I need to return each name plus each value from the html source code below or a similar one. Example: {_pn_Brand:Dell}. Everything good so far.

My problem is that the source code contains one or more parameters (in my example below: _pn_Hardware Connectivity, _pn_Features) which can be found several times in the source code and I only need to return the checked ones.

To be more specific I need to return something like: {_pn_Hardware Connectivity:HDMI,USB 2.0}, {_pn_Features:Backlit Keyboard,Bluetooth,Built-in Microphone,Built-in Webcam}.

Please keep in mind that the attributes names like _pn_Hardware Connectivity or _pn_Features can change in other source codes so I need a foreach function to generally solve my problem.

I hope you guys understand exactly what I'm looking for. My apologise for the poor explanation but couldn't think of a better one for the moment. Please check the html source code below:

```
<input type="text" name="_pn_Brand" size="21" maxlength="50" gname="Brand" value="Dell">
<input type="text" name="_pn_MPN" size="21" maxlength="50" value="">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Type" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Notebook/Laptop">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Screen Size" size="21" maxlength="50" value="17 in">
<input type="text" name="_pn_RAM Size" size="21" maxlength="50" value="16 GB">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Processor" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Intel Core i7 4th Gen Quad core.">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Graphics Processing Type" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Dedicated Graphics">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Manufacturer Colour" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Black">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Manufacturer warranty" size="21" maxlength="50" value="None" closed="true">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Processor Speed" size="21" maxlength="50" value="2.50- 3.20 GHz">
<input type="text" name="_pn_pnorage Type" size="21" maxlength="50" value="HDD (Hard Disk Drive)">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Hard Drive Capacity" size="21" maxlength="50" value="500 GB">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Operating System" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Windows 10">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Operating System Edition" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Professional">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Release Year" size="21" maxlength="50" value="2014">
<input type="text" name="_pn_Colour" size="21" maxlength="50" value="Black">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="DisplayPort">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="Mini DisplayPort">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="HDMI" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="Micro-HDMI">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="Micro-USB">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="Mini-USB">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="USB 1.0/1.1">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="USB 2.0" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="USB 3.0">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Hardware Connectivity" value="USB 3.1">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="10/100 LAN Card">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="3D Camera">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Backlit Keyboard" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Bluetooth" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Built-in Microphone" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Built-in Webcam" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="HSDPA">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Tablet PC">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Touchscreen">
<input type="checkbox" name="_pn_Features" value="Virtual Reality Ready">
```

Thanks to everyone that can help in advance!

PHP code so far (from OP's comment)

```
foreach(explode('name="pn', $source) as $tags){ 
    $tag = explode('', $tags); 
    $tag = explode('"', $tag[1]); 
    $value = explode('value="', $tags); 
    $value = explode('"', $value[1]); 
    echo '{_pn'.$tag[0].':'.$value[0].'}'; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide code changes that you have implemented so far.

Comment: Why not just submit the `form` of inputs and process them as `$_POST` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an array based on description you have provided.( Assuming you are getting the same data as defined for $str )

```
$str = 'vehicle=Bike&a1=Bike&a1=Bike&vehicle=Car';

$new_arr = [];
foreach( explode ("&", $str) as $val) {


    $key = substr($val.'=', 0, strpos($val, '='));

    $value = substr($val, strpos($val, "=") + 1);    
    if (in_array($key, $new_arr)) {
        $new_arr[$key] [$value] ;
    } else {
        $new_arr[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($new_arr); 

Array
(
    [vehicle] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bike
            [1] => Car
        )

    [a1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bike
            [1] => Bike
        )

)
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Many Thanks. It works but not sure how to output it as echo and save it into .txt document for future use. Can you help me out with that as well?

Comment: @Iain try doing some reaseach or perhaps employ a PHP developer?

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to first group the input in two groups:
Input group and Checkbox group
Then you can create variables and loop to display the inputs:

```html
<php
 $inputGroup = [
  ['_pn_Brand', 21, 50, 'Brand', 'Dell'],
  ['_pn_MPN', 21, 50, '', ''],
  ...
 ];

 $checkboxGroup = [
  ['_pn_Hardware Connextivity', [
   'DisplayPort',
   'Mini DisplayPort',
   ...
  ]],
  ['_pn_Features', [
   '10/100 LAN Card',
   '3D Camera',
   ...
  ]]
 ];

 // Then you loop each varaible to display the inputs
 foreach($inputGroup as $input)
 {
  echo '<input type="text" name="'. $input[0] .'" size="'. $input[1] .'" maxlength="'. $input[2] .'" gname="'. $input[3] .'" value="'. $input[4] .'">';
 }
 foreach($checkboxGroup as $checkbox)
 {
  foreach($checkbox[1] as $value)
  {
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'. $checkbox[0] .'" value="'. $value .'">'
  }
 }

?>
```

Comment: @Patrissoll Kenfack I think you didn't understood exactly what I am looking for or I can't quite understand your code. Like I have mentioned the attributes names like _pn_Hardware Connectivity or _pn_Features can change in other source codes so I need a foreach function to generally solve my problem. In fact all the attributes are changing if for example my source code contains TV specifics but I only have problems getting the checked values from checkbox options.